# AWS Site Returning 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an AWS site and received an email that my account was hacked. I made the following changes to resolve this issue:

1. I changed my password
2. Created a new access key
3. Deleted the IAM users that were not created by me
4. Enabled multi-factor authentication
5. Created new Amazon SES SMTP credentials
6. Deleted the existing Amazon SES credentials in IAM

My site no longer works after these changes. I'm receiving a 500 internal server error when trying to make a fetch request.

Submitting the following CURL request doesn't return anything useful:

```
curl -H "Origin: harperinspect.com" -v "https://0io16pktb6.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev"
```

I'm at a loss for how to fix this and I need to get this site back up.

Comment: If it stopped working after you made these changes, it could be an IAM user/role got removed that the application needed to function. Some more details on your application might help to narrow down the issue. Is this affecting the entire backend or specific components, and where are they hosted (EC2/ECS/Lambda etc)?

Comment: I would look at the logs from your server.  It's possible that something on your site was compromised too.